# HTML string not appear in webview

Tags: android, html, android-webview, android-volley

I Receive `Html String` response from `volley` my issue is I'm not able to display this response in webview it's display empty webview

I used `Webview.loadData(response,"text/html","UTF-8");`  as well  `webview.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, response, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);` and nothing appear

also I enabled all this but still got nothing

```
// Configure related browser settings
        mweb.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
        mweb.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);

        mweb.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        // Zoom out if the content width is greater than the width of the viewport
        mweb.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        // Enable responsive layout
        mweb.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        mweb.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);

        mweb.getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
        mweb.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);

        mweb.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);

        mweb.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
        mweb.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true); // allow pinch to zooom
        mweb.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false); // disable the default zoom controls on the page
        mweb.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        mweb.getSettings().setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8");
```

in mainfest I add this also

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
```

and still face the same issue the webview is blank

Answer (score 0):

after Long search and debug the issue was in load webview inside this which prevent webview from appear

```
           runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
               @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
               @Override
           public void run() {
                    mweb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    mweb.loadDataWithBaseURL("",data, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);

               }
         });
```